# How to change the string type list to a list type and then drop nan elements

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a unique problem. I am facing two issues here. First, my list is a string type, not list type. Then, some of the elements in the list are nan. I want to drop them.

My code:

```
x = '[1.4,2.3,nan]'
print(type(x)) # prints str
x = eval(x) # with this I want to drop end quotes, convert it to list type
print(type(x))
x = [k for k in x if str(k)!='nan']
```

Present output:

```
NameError: name 'nan' is not defined
```

Expected output:

```
x = [1.4,2.3]
```

Comment: @wwii my whole problem actually solved by defining nan. Because my code throws nan name error as if it is an unknown variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't use `eval` for anything if you're not acutely aware how unsafe it is. Instead, properly parse your input.

```
import math

s = '[1.4,2.3,nan]'
x = [float(n) for n in s.lstrip('[').rstrip(']').split(',')]
x = [n for n in x if not math.isnan(n)]
```

Comment: can you let how `eval` could be unsafe? Maybe I am not fully aware of it. I thought it correct because it helps me to convert the string to list type.

Comment: Here're details about [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/2063361) . There's a `ast.literal_eval` which is safe alternative to `eval`, but has some restrictions. And because of that, `literal_eval` is unable to parse 'nan' in your list string

Comment: @Mainland Look at my comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66052748/how-to-change-the-string-type-list-to-a-list-type-and-then-drop-nan-elements/66052887?noredirect=1#comment116783792_66052773.

Answer (score 1):

Define it then.

```
x = '[1.4,2.3,nan]'
nan = float('nan') # here
x = eval(x) 
x = [k for k in x if str(k)!='nan']
```

Also a better way to remove `nan`s is to check if they are equal to their self.

```
x = [k for k in x if k==k]
```

Comment: Hey, your new list is `[1.4,2.3,exec("import os;os.system('rm -rf yourdata')") or 1.2]`, does your answer work on that?

Comment: @orlp I am using OP's code that uses `eval`.

Comment: ...may I ask why?

Comment: @orlp  They did not specify that they wanted another method to parse it. Trying to answer only what was asked.

Comment: This is a gem solution. Because the line `nan = float('nan')` is actually what I am missing in my whole solution. Always I was worried that `nan` is throwing name error like undefined variable. With this lines, now it stands defined and gets removed in the next line.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative to achieve this by converting string to comma sperated list of numbers. And then I am filtering out the `'nan'` string inside the *list comprehension* as:

```
>>> my_str = '[1.4,2.3,nan]'

>>> [float(x) for x in my_str[1:-1].split(',') if x!='nan']
[1.4, 2.3]
```

And here's a *functional* approach to achieve this using [**`math.isnan()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isnan) and [**`itertools.filterfalse()`**](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse) as:

```
>>> from itertools import filterfalse
>>> from math import isnan

>>> my_str = '[1.4,2.3,nan]'

>>> list(filterfalse(isnan, map(float, my_str[1:-1].split(','))))
[1.4, 2.3]
```

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

```
x = '[1.4,2.3,nan]'
x = list(x.strip('[]').split(','))
x = [float(i) for i in x if i!='nan']
print(x)
```